# How to pass a different request header for each origin (hostname) configured for an origin type in azure front door?

Tags: azure, rules, azure-front-door, azure-traffic-manager

Lets say I have 3 endpoints configured on default origin type in Azure front door. Below are the sample endpoints

1. https://example1.com
2. https://example2.com
3. https://example3.com

Here is my final azure front door endpoint with equal priority and equal weight for above configured endpoints.

1. https://abcfrontdoor.azurefd.net

So whenever front door url is hit, if it picks first endpoint, I need to add a request header 'api-key' with some value 12345. Similarly when other endpoint hits, a different request header has to be passed.

I explored rulesets but it works on front door endpoint and not the origin endpoints. Looking for answers. Let me know if there are other ways to achieve this.

Comment: I dont think this is doable right now

Comment: Yes, Even I think so. I have enabled APIM with 3 endpoints. Any suggestions on how to load balance them?

Comment: Not exactly what you need but I actually build a similar load balancing mechanism in APIM, you might be able to take some inspiration from that https://github.com/Azure/teams-event-distributor/blob/main/deployment/module_apim.bicep#L150